# TCL: how to check if environment variable already set

Tags: environment-variables, tcl, environment-modules

I am trying to construct a module file and I would like to include an if statement to check whether certain environment variables (e.g. PATH, LD_LIBRAY_PATH, PYTHON_PATH, ...) have already been set.

I have tried several different syntax options (after searching on here, official documentation and other forums) but when I then try:

```tcl
module use modulefiles
module load mymodule
```

I keep getting `ERROR:102: Tcl command execution failed` error. Here are a few of the options that I have tried:

i)

```go
set myTools /path/to/my/Tools
if { info exists $LD_LIBRARY_PATH } {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTool/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
} else {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTools/lib64
}
```

ii)

```
set myTools /path/to/my/Tools
if { [info exists $LD_LIBRARY_PATH] } {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTool/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
} else {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTools/lib64
}
```

iii)

```go
set myTools /path/to/my/Tools
if { $?LD_LIBRARY_PATH } {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTool/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
} else {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTools/lib64
}
```

What is the correct syntax to check for the existence of environment variables that may have already been set, e.g. in a `.cshrc` or `.login` file?

Apologies if this is a basic question. I've done stuff like this before in the shell (mainly csh), but I am new to TCL and building module files, so any help and advice wold be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The http://wiki.tcl.tk/1624 about env contains probably the answer to your question.

Following the hints given in the other answers and the wiki link given above I constructed following code which works for me.

```
if { [info exists ::env(IDL_PATH)] } {
   if {![string match *<IDL_DEFAULT>* $::env(IDL_PATH)]} {
   puts stderr "Warning: ill defined IDL_PATH environment variable
   }
} else {
setenv  IDL_PATH        "<IDL_DEFAULT>"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It really helps if you have the actual error message and not the summary “something went wrong”.

Generally speaking, environment variables are mapped into elements of the global `env` array in Tcl; they don't just become individual global variables (as that would be open to too much abuse). Also, when talking *about* a variable you don't read from it and so don't prefix it with `$` (which in Tcl is *strictly* a read operation). That said, using the `setenv` is important because that is about manipulating the environment in the caller, not in the Tcl code itself.

So we use a variation on your second attempt.

```
set myTools /path/to/my/Tools
if { [info exists env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)] } {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTool/lib64:$env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
} else {
    setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $myTools/lib:$myTools/lib64
}
```

The problem with the first attempt is that you need to use square-bracket syntax to use the output of a Tcl command. The problem with the third one is that `$?` doesn't mean anything to Tcl at all (I guess we could change that, but it would be a long road to walk and it doesn't help you now).

Answer (score 3):

the env global array could be also used to set the value of the environment variable, and it is better to use ::env instead of env to access it from the level 0 (or declare it as `global env`)

```
set myTools /path/to/my/Tools
if { [info exists ::env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)] } {
    set ::env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) $myTools/lib:$myTool/lib64:$env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
} else {
    set ::env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) $myTools/lib:$myTools/lib64
}
```